# Different output for same statement run twice in python shell using pycrypto library

Tags: python-2.7, pycrypto

I was experimenting with pycrypto library with below setup.
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 x86_64
Python Version:2.7.12
pycrypto version: 2.6.1

I am not able to understand why there is a difference in output of 2nd last and 3rd last statement though both are exactly same.
when i run this statement again the output shown in 2nd last is repeated.
I am not able to reproduce this behaviour but i wonder what could have caused this.

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> message = "The answer is no"
>>> ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
>>> ciphertext
'\xd6\x83\x8dd!VT\x92\xaa`A\x05\xe0\x9b\x8b\xf1'
>>> obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
'The answer is no'
>>> obj2.decrypt(obj.encrypt(message))
'The answer is no'
>>> obj.decrypt(obj.encrypt(message))
'\x0c\x14\xceA\x9cq\x8d\x07\xbb,\xa9G6\x14\x81s'
>>> obj2.decrypt(obj.encrypt(message))
'\x0c\x14\xceA\x9cq\x8d\x07\xbb,\xa9G6\x14\x81s'
>>> obj2.decrypt(obj.encrypt(message))
'The answer is no'
>>> obj2.decrypt(obj.encrypt(message))
'The answer is no'
```

Comment: You may want to look into the meaning of *stateful* - `decrypt()` is a stateful call so you can break up the message and call `decrypt()` multiple times for the same message. From the docstring (try `help(obj.decrypt)`: "That also means that you cannot reuse an object for encrypting or decrypting other data with the same key."

Comment: @AChampion That's a complete answer in my book.